# Tensorflow FIFOQueue error: FIFOQueue is closed and has insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow

Now I am using tensorflow to write a program to validate models. I use the FIFOQueue to queue the input data. For example, I have 50,000 images and enqueue 100 images at a time. The program works beautifully except for the final iteration. At the final iteration, it shows the error 
"E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] FIFOQueue '_0_path_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: path_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeue_class=["loc:@path_queue"], component_types=[DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_STRING], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]"

I think that is because it tries to enqueue the 50,001~50,100 images but cannot achieve this. However, I don't need to enqueue these images and will not use them. How can I avoid this error?

Another question is that if I would like to use dequeue_many(100), however, the total number of images is not divisible by 100, say 45678. In this case, tensorflow will throw an error. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `dequeue_up_to` instead of `dequeue_many`:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the specific error which will gracefully end training once all examples have been exhausted:

```
try:
    while True:
        # Run training Ops here...

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue multiple times and from my experience this is usually caused if the input files cannot be found. my input was a list of pngs from a directory and I was using this to get the input images.

```
input = tensorflow.train.string_input_producer(tensorflow.train.match_filenames_once("/input/*.png"))
```

which was somehow not getting the files correctly. Changing it to

```
filename_im = tensorflow.train.string_input_producer(glob.glob('/input/*.png'))
```

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is only a warning that the queue is empty, but does not cause errors. I see similar warnings but my program does not break. Does yours?  See [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/923).